# Windows command prompt help in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

This comes more or less from idle curiosity. I've been using DOS since the ear;y 80s, and before that CP/M-86. In the past several years, I've pretty much shifted to PowerShell. However, by habit of long standing, I still use the old DOS commands. In the Windows command prompt, I've been typing:

```
help dir
help dir > dirhelp.txt
help > doshelp.txt
```

Here's the question, and the answer most probably is, "No." Is there any PowerShell command (or cmd-let) that produces help for Windows commands?

Yeah, I know it's crazy, but inquiring minds want to know. 'gal' is the closest thing I use, but I miss the terse but useful DOS help.

Comment: Not sure if I'm oversimplifying but `help dir` roughly equals: `get-help Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: Command.com was a command interpreter for DOS. What information are you looking for?

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. Why would you want help with `command.com`?  It doesn't exist at all on 64-bit Windows, and on 32-bit versions it's a 16-bit MS-DOS program. You seem to be confusing the Windows command prompt (`cmd`) with an obsolete 16-bit operating system commonly called DOS.  The command prompt on Windows is not DOS and doesn't use `command.com`.

Comment: Why? No reason other than it's something I've been living with for almost 40 years, and I wondered if it still lives. It does!  Hooray!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the output you'd expect from running help in cmd.exe even when run in PowerShell. If that's what you're asking for?

```
help.exe dir
help.exe dir > dirhelp.txt
help.exe > doshelp.txt
```

Comment: Bingo. Thanks, I like it!

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell has a really good help system that can be used in a few different ways, I tend to use a combination of them methods below:

**Get all PowerShell cmdlets:**
`Get-Command`

**Find all cmdlets with help:**
`Get-Command "*help*`

**Find help with specific cmdlets:**
`Get-Help Get-ChildItem`

**Find cmdlets with Aliases:**
`Get-Alias`

***You can even do things like:***
`Get-Help Dir -Examples` or `Get-Help Dir -Online`

Hope this helps!

Nice Article for some further reading:
https://www.darkoperator.com/blog/2013/1/15/powershell-basicsusing-the-help-subsystem.html

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.
Snarky answer: Sure - the command is

```
start-process "http://www.mdgx.com/secrets.htm"
```

In Powershell, as I am sure you're familiar, one would use the Get-Help command to get help for any command provided you have the help subsystem up-to-date.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Hats off to notjustme --- HELP.EXE Try it, you'll like it.